# Contact Form Message Send Animation

Tags: php, html, css, forms, phpmailer

got a quick question about my contact form. When u send a message then the page reload and u coming to the header of the page. I would like to have it that you stay on the contact section when u send the message and that under the send button a text shows up like "hey, the message is send" I got in the code my homepage as link but I have a one-age site so I dont know how to fix the section that it stands on the contact section...

here is the code from the phpmailer:

```
<?php
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

    require 'src/Exception.php';
    require 'src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'src/SMTP.php';

    $mail = new PHPMailer(true);                              // Passing `true` enables exceptions
    try {
        //Server settings
        $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;                                 // Enable verbose debug output
        $mail->isSMTP();                                      // Set mailer to use SMTP
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.test.de';  // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                               // Enable SMTP authentication
        $mail->Username = 'MY EMAIL';                 // SMTP username
        $mail->Password = 'MY PASSWORT!';                           // SMTP password
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                           // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
        $mail->Port = 465;                                    // TCP port to connect to

        //Recipients
        $mail->setFrom('MY EMAIL');
        $mail->addAddress($_POST['mail']);     // Add a recipient



        //Content
        $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
        $mail->Subject = $_POST['subject'];
        $mail->Body    = $_POST['text'];

        $mail->send();
        //echo 'Message has been sent';
        header('Location: http://www.example.com/contact.php');
        exit();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    ?>
```

if you need the homepage to see what I mean: www.yveslumiere.com

Cheers Yves :-)

Comment: Read up on [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX/Getting_Started), which allows you to post the form in the background, without reloading the page.

Comment: If you don’t want to use AJAX, which will probably require quite a bit of re-writing of the logic, then you can also jump back to any HTML anchor point, by adding a hash portion to the URL your script is currently redirecting back to.

Comment: okay that was easy haha now it works ... but now no message shows up that the message is send ... I have this code inside the phpmailer:
```
  $mail->send();
        //echo 'Message has been sent';
        header('Location: https://www.yveslumiere.com/#contact');
    echo 'Message has been sent';
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo 'Message could not be sent.';
    echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: HMM is that a dynamic site or a html template on www.yveslumiere.com ? :)

Comment: Ihm its a Template from Themeforrest :-)